# Production build failed from Bootstrap 5 gem on Netlify

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, jekyll, bootstrap-5, netlify

I cloned a repository for using Jekyll 4 and the Bootstrap 5 gem.
https://github.com/MichaelCurrin/jekyll-bootstrap-quickstart

It work locally but not in production.

I use Netlify as hosting service. The build is done from the fetched gem but @import "bootstrap-5.1.3/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap" seems pointing in the wrong path, how can i point the @import to 'opt/build/cache/bundle' in production mode ? Thx

```
10:52:00 AM: Using sassc-rails 2.1.2
10:52:00 AM: Fetching bootstrap 5.1.3
10:52:00 AM: Installing bootstrap 5.1.3
10:52:00 AM: Bundle complete! 3 Gemfile dependencies, 57 gems now installed.
10:52:00 AM: Bundled gems are installed into `/opt/build/cache/bundle`
10:52:00 AM: Gem bundle installed
```

```
bundle exec jekyll build
10:52:02 AM: Configuration file: /opt/build/repo/_config.yml
10:52:02 AM:             Source: /opt/build/repo
10:52:02 AM:        Destination: /opt/build/repo/_site
10:52:02 AM:  Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
10:52:02 AM:       Generating...
10:52:02 AM:   Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'assets/css/styles.scss':
10:52:02 AM:                     Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-5.1.3/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap. on line 7:1 of styles.scss >> @import "bootstrap-5.1.3/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap"; ^ 
10:52:02 AM:                     ------------------------------------------------
10:52:02 AM:       Jekyll 4.2.2   Please append `--trace` to the `build` command 
10:52:02 AM:                      for any additional information or backtrace. 
10:52:02 AM:                     ------------------------------------------------
```

config.yml

```
### Site metadata

title: My site
description: Starter template for using Jekyll 4 and the Bootstrap gem

sass:
  load_paths:
    - _sass/
    - vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/

defaults:
  - scope:
      path: "*.md"
    values:
      layout: page

exclude:
  - LICENSE
  - README.md
   - Makefile
  - sample.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, instead of the use of the gem "bootstrap", i copied/paste the bootstrap library in the CSS folder.

[more info on this method:](https://experimentingwithcode.com/creating-a-jekyll-blog-with-bootstrap-4-and-sass-part-1/)